# Optimize group by array value with join query

Tags: sql, postgresql

Using Postgres 15 and having over 10 million rows in a ledger like table.
Here is a simplified version of it:

```
|id |user_id | amount| tags                 |
|---|--------|-------|----------------------|
| 1 |112233  |100    |{market, tag1, tag2}  | 
| 2 |112233  |20     |{market, tag1, tag2}  |
| 3 |112233  |200    |{gas, tag1, tag2}     |
| 4 |112233  |40     |{cinema, tag1, tag2}  |
```

What I want to accomplish is to write a select query for summing up the user's amounts by category. The category is part of the tags array column (only 1 such entry) which also stores other tag types that can be ignored here.
Also I have another table for (1 to 1) mapping the tag values to my own category definition. The select will return the category from this table.

```
|id | tag     | category       |
|---|---------|----------------|
| 1 | market  | groceries      |
| 2 | gas     | transportation |
| 3 | cinema  | entertainment  |
```

The query result I'm looking for:

```
| total   | category       |
|---------|----------------|
| 120     | groceries      |
| 200     | transportation |
| 40      | entertainment  |
```

I wrote this query for that:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) as total, tc.tag as category
FROM myschema.tag_category tc
JOIN myschema.ledger l 
ON tc.category = ANY(l.tags)
WHERE l.user_id = '112233' 
GROUP BY tc.tag
```

I have also added these 2 indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX ON myschema.ledger(user_id);
CREATE INDEX ON myschema.points_ledger USING GIN (tags);
```

It takes ~400 milliseconds to run in pgAdmin.
What would be a more performant query for accomplishing this, what should I change?

Comment: It is possible to write this query, but it would be much easier and run much faster if you didn't have a broken schema for the tags.

Comment: You mean having to do the join with the other table? Would it be much better if I would directly save the mapped tags in the array column? Or something else?

Comment: You would do much better to move the tags column to its own table, with one row for each tag/id entry. Avoid using array columns.

Comment: I am actually just adding that tags column to the schema, so I am able to test that approach as well. I will test it out, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to your Query, You will need to add some compound indexes :

```
CREATE INDEX ON ledger(tags, user_id);

CREATE INDEX ON tag_category (tag, category);
```

This is an other way to get your desired data :

```
SELECT SUM(amount) as total, tc.category as category
FROM tag_category tc
JOIN ledger l ON l.tags like '%' || tc.tag || '%'
WHERE l.user_id = '112233' 
GROUP BY tc.category;
```

Comment: Hey, I did already include that way of querying in the post. I am looking to find a more performant way of doing it.

Comment: Then I misunderstand the question :)

Comment: Adding those indexes did not help. I'm running the query with EXPLAIN ANALYZE and the indexes are not being hit. I've been reading and it turns out that when indexing arrays GIN type indexes should be used. Also array operators should be used in order to work. I have updated the query to use such and also added GIN indexes, but still the query plan does not make use of any index. I really don't get it.